# Asp.net hosting provider with build capabilities and source control

Tags: asp.net, version-control, continuous-integration, hosting

Can you suggest an asp.net 3.5 hosting provider with continuous integration (cctray – nant builds) and source control facilities (svn)?

My requirement would be something like this:

- I checkin to a svn branch (say trunk) on the hosting provider space.
- CruiseControl.NET on the server fires off a build.
- I see success/failure on my cctray.
- On success my peers go to the website (say http://trunk.mywebsite.com) and see changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would also have to suggest a VPS as I have yet to see a Shared Hosting provider with compilers installed.

On the code repository side [Assembla.com](http://www.assembla.com/) has free svn hosting and they also provide a way to kick off a build process by allowing you to specify a URL to post to when a check-in occurs. This URL can kick off a script that pulls the latest code and builds it. You can find more details on how to set this up [here](http://blog.assembla.com/assemblablog/tabid/12618/bid/2916/Running-builds-from-Assembla-repositories.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Shared hosting providers doesn't have that. You'll probably have to go with VPS, or maybe even Dedicated if services  are consuming too much processor/ram.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone here. For every custom demands, it would be cheaper to look on a VPS / dedicated server to perform what you ask. You may find what you need, but at a high cost.